# DBpedia - Can't Extract private/surname etc. in non english language

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I'm trying to get private name (actually more data like surename,abstract etc.) from dbpedia. 
I manage to do it in english, but can't in other languages (JA,Ru and more)

```
SELECT distinct * 
WHERE {
?p a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person>.
?p foaf:givenName ?firstname .
?p rdfs:label ?label .
}
LIMIT 1000
```

Results:

```
   p       firstname        label
:Andreas_Ekberg [http]  "Andreas"@en    "Andreas Ekberg"@it
:Andreas_Ekberg [http]  "Andreas"@en    "Andreas Ekberg"@nl
:Andreas_Ekberg [http]  "Andreas"@en    "Andreas Ekberg"@en
```

Thanks!

Comment: ok, but what's the question now? The resource http://dbpedia.org/resource/Andreas_Ekberg exists only in those 3 DBpedia Chapters. Open the resource in the browser and check the `owl:sameAs` links. Moreover, I can't see any Russian DBpedia chapter at all according to the list (not sufe if this up-to-date indeed): https://wiki.dbpedia.org/join/chapters . And if you go to the corresponding Wikipedia page, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andreas_Ekberg , I can see any page for Japanese nor Russia.

Comment: Remember that DBpedia is incomplete, just like Wikipedia upon which it is based. You can only get data out, when that data has been loaded. Start by finding an entity that has the language variations you want, and then use that to build a generic query. (You will find more "up-to-date" extraction in [DBpedia Live](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql) than in [DBpedia "Snapshot"](http://dbpedia.org/sparql).)